# Sidebar not opening when clicked on a toggled. element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i'm currently working on a project where the user wants to be able to open the sidebar when the hamburger button on the `header` is not visible . To accomplish  this task I made a button that only is shown when the `header` is out of view. The problem that is accruing is that the `showSidebar` function is not being executed. I also tried to put the functionality of the  `showSidebar` directly in to the `addEventListener` as an anonymous function, with the same results.

The side bar is being closed whenever I click on anything that is not inside the sidebar or the hamburger button itself.

```js
function showSidebar() {
    sidebar.classList.add('show');
    overlay.classList.add('enabled');
}

function togglePill() {
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    if (scrolled <= 69) {
        locationPill.classList.remove('show');
    } else if (scrolled > 69) {
        locationPill.classList.add('show');

        locationPill.addEventListener('click', showSidebar);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', togglePill);
```

Comment: There is no need to use `locationPill.addEventListener` every time you show the button. You can add the listener once, since you do not destroy the button, but merely hide it.

You probably need to provide a complete code example. The information that you have provided is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the hide sidebar function is not toggled when you are clicking on the location pill

```js
document.addEventListener('click',
  e => !sidebar.contains(e.target)
       && e.target.parentElement !== hamburgerBtn
       && !e.target.classList.contains('location')
       && !e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('location') ?
            hideSidebar() : false
);
```